# GTA 5 weapon wheel

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just started playing GTA 5, it recently became free so I downloaded it. I wanted to know how to change my weapon to a different gun but the same class of gun and can’t figure it out on pc. Like I have 3 pistols and can’t figure out how to equip any except the default.

Comment: After looking online it seems you could try scrolling the mouse wheel while over the gun class you want to swap through.

Answer (score 1):

On **PC**, if you activate the weapon wheel (Q) you can hover over the weapon type you want. If you want (and own) another weapon of the same type, scrolling the mouse wheel will allow you to change into that other weapon.

For example, if you  own both the AP Pistol and the Silenced Pistol, you over the top center portion and use the mouse wheel to swap between AP and Silenced Pistol.

Do note that the Weapon Wheel will also show you how many weapons of the type you're hovering you own.